# How to configure mvn/Jrebel/wtp/gwt/eclipse to work smoothly with changes on the service interface

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, jrebel

I started to investigate the `guice-rf-activities` artifact with the new maven gwt plugin from Thomas Broyer.

I played a little bit with the code and added a function on the `GreetingService` on the serverside. I followed down the path and added the required bits and bytes until the code was properly calling either the `greetServer` or `insultServer` method.

I found, that a simple SDM recompile did not make the method available on the server. Restarting the Tomcat did not help either. Saving a file in eclipse did not trigger the compile properly.

In the end, running a full module compile did the trick.

I see this as a problem, as any change on the service will potentially give you some time for coffee on large projects. Is there some "trick", I did not do, or is the complexity of RequestFactory code generation that heavy, that I cannot simply use the SDM + JRebel or server restart to change the service interfaces?

**UPDATE:** The way described by Thomas (thanks!) works, if you plan to start your tomcat with the maven tomcat target.

**UPDATE2:** Described the `launcherDir` approach to get the wtp/eclipse/mvn/Jrebel to run.

If you want to use the eclipse wtp tomcat launcher and, as I do, JRebel, to compile your server-classes on the fly, the JRebel reload will not catch the ofuscated RF service names.
To fix this, add the following JVM attribute to your wtp launch configuration (thanks, Thomas!):

`-Dgwt.rf.ServiceLayerCache=false`

When the server interface changes, the following happens
(eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), JRebel 6.x):

- change your service and context classes as required

  - you see JRebel reloading the class
- call `mvn process-classes` on the commandline

  - you see JRebel reloading the obfuscationfactory
- SDM compile in the browser (F5 will do the trick)

  - Your service is now working in the client

**Linking the gwt client code with the wtp server**

To link the codeserver with the wtp environment, the `src/main/webapp` folder needs to contain your GWT code folder. 
To achieve this, the codeserver must be directed to generate the SDM stub at the right location. Add a property to the `module/pom.xml` as such:

```
<properties>    
    <gwt.launcherDir>${project.build.directory}/gwt/launcherDir</gwt.launcherDir>
</properties>
```

Additionally, configure the gwt maven plugin to use the property instead:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <configuration>
        <launcherDir>${gwt.launcherDir}</launcherDir>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ...
```

To run the codeserver inside eclipse or on the commandline, give the proper definition for `gwt.launcherDir` to maven. I am using a 
small cmd to run the codeserver for eclipse:

```
mvn -Dgwt.launcherDir=module-app-server\src\main\webapp gwt:codeserver
```

This way, the "recompile on f5" works very nice and smooth. This is finally the full integration of GWT in eclipse with maven and JRebel. Wow. Kudos to @TBroyer :-)

Comment: Could it be that the annotation processor didn't run after the change? It's required for the server (and then reload the webapp in the server). Client-side should Just Work™ with a browser refresh, even though I must admit I haven't verified. Will try when I find some time.

Comment: Client side worked immediately (had to hit the compile button in the browser, though), but the apt compiler did not trigger. I had changed the apt settings in server and shared project, otherwise the server would not have started at all.

Comment: When using wtp-tomcat, you should set the `CodeServer`'s `-launcherDir` to where WTP publishes your app; similarly to how you'd run "classic" DevMode previously: https://web.archive.org/web/20130619170526/https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_in_eclipse_for_java_ee

Comment: This doesn't compute, because the maven plugin creates the files in the target folder, not in the main/src/webapp. But that is the location where wtp runs from.

Comment: The plugin creates them where you tell it to: see `<launcherDir>` in the root POM; replace it with a property so you can override at runtime (or just run CodeServer from within Eclipse, without Maven). As for the location WTP uses, see linked FAQ (I don't use WTP myself).

Comment: Honestly, it works very well now :-) I will give it a try, but we had in the past all kinds of strange RPC out of sync problems, when we forced the plugin and Google Eclipse Plugin to play nice with the wtp server. These issues are now all gone with the described setup - and it was really just adding that one folder to the deployment target and the define - but okay, if all works well when relocating the launcherDir AND the automatic reload works, then that's actually not only milk and honey, but like organic milk and honey :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client side doesn't need anything special. The server side though requires the `RequestFactory` and all its `RequestContext` and proxies hierarchy to be processed by the *validation tool*.

From the command line, in the context of the archetypes, that means launching the `process-classes` phase on the `*-server` module, e.g.

```
mvn process-classes -pl *-server -am
```

With the `mvn tomcat7:run -Denv=dev` running, Tomcat should detect the class changes and automatically reload the webapp.

Then just refresh the page in the browser, and after authenticating again (reloading the webapp in Tomcat loses the session/authentication) you can see the changes end-to-end.

Steps to reproduce:

1. create the project
2. in one terminal, launch `mvn gwt:codeserver -pl *-client -am`
3. in another terminal, launch `mvn tomcat7:run -pl *-server -am -Denv=dev`
4. open `http://localhost:8080` in your browser, sign into the webapp and notice the client-side app compiling automatically (that's the new SDM in GWT 2.7)
5. edit `*-shared/src/main/java/**/GreetingContext.java` and duplicate `greetServer` as `insultServer`
6. similarly, edit `*-server/src/main/java/**/GreetingService.java` and duplicate `greetServer` and `insultServer` (change the `Hello` message into an insult to feel the change)
7. edit `*-client/src/main/java/**/GreetingActivity.java` and replace the call to `greetServer` to a call to `insultServer` (or add another button and duplicate the code)
8. in yet another terminal, run `mvn process-classes -pl *-server -am`; notice that Tomcat reloads the webapp
9. Refresh the page in the browser, sign in again, and notice the client-side app recompiling. Hit the button and get insulted rather than greeted. QED.

The *validation tool* can be configured as an annotation processor in your IDE; see https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation for the details. Note that Eclipse is notoriously bad (broken?) wrt annotation processing; it might be better to **not** run the processor *in the editor* as they call it (i.e. incrementally) and instead trigger a project build when you're done (that should –hopefully– be equivalent to the `mvn process-classes`), or you could just launch the `mvn process-classes` from within Eclipse.

Note that I advise against launching `mvn gwt:codeserver` and `mvn tomcat7:run` from within Eclipse, as Eclipse hard-kills processes, which generally causes the `CodeServer` to stay alive (it's a forked process), and won't run your JVM shutdown hooks or `ServletContextListener`'s `contextDestroyed`.

Comment: It works as described. I still have an issue with JRebel integration. When tomcat is run in WTP (I added the target/../<module> folder to deployment assembly), the classes are reloaded properly, but the obfuscation is missing. I suppose the reason is the obfuscation proxy. I see an obfuscator beeing reloaded after `process-classes` in the commandline. Does the obfuscation require another class to be present, that is outside the module folder?

Comment: Is the `xxxFactoryDeobfuscatorBuilder` using only static methods? Or, you know where the generated java code for that class is?

Comment: You cannot get the Java code when running the `ValidationTool`, but if you use it as an annotation processor then you can instruct `javac` to output the generated Java code to a given folder. Eclipse always outputs the Java code of annotation processors to a folder (defaulting to `.apt_generated` in the project). The class is loaded via reflection, and does *not* have static methods (the method return values are cached though, so reloading only the class would be useless). You can disable that cache with the `gwt.rf.ServiceLayerCache` system property though (set it to `false`). HTH